# Corroboration in Popper's system

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, popper

Why does corroboration give increasing "value" to a theory, as he states in his "Logic of Scientific Discovery"?

The question is simple, but I need a complex answer, one that can't be used to justify inductive probability.

Comment: So given your response that I did not address the question you need to clarify the question.  By "value" you mean 'trustworthiness' and by corroboration you mean 'replication'.  'Value' for Popper is often overall predictive power instead of the expectation of repeatability, and 'corroboration' often means independent and not similar testing of subtheories related to the main theory, not repetition of the same experiments.  As it is you are asking why repetition predicts repeatability absent any theory of induction.  You could ask that more directly.

Comment: The answer is basically that Popper fails.  He does not understand the power of the base-rate fallacy and confirmation bias.  And he has been taken to task for it by the next generation of historians of science.  If you remove those problems, Baysian inference explains induction via Lapace's rule of succession.  The odds of failure given past success becomes a geometric sequence that converges to a fixed chance of replication.  Unfortunately, the observed history says humans are highly base-rate insensitive and when they try to correct for that, they do it in a confirmation-biased manner.

Comment: @jobermark Ye you are right i was not really clear.  I'll read it with attention later and tell you if i got it or not, thank you.

Comment: @jobermark i'm not sure if I got it, i'll describe the problem with an example. I have a beautiful theory in my mind, perfect for popper's standards. If i have 0 ecperiments on that theory, that theory of course has 0 attendability. If it succeded 1 experiment, it has low attendability. If it succeded 100? And 10.000? Surelly at the point 10.000 it is more attendable than at the point 100. But why? Popper states that, and i don't think he is so stupid to not even think  about a reason that doesn't imply induction. Or is he?

Comment: So yeah, that direction sort of works.  Your theory, if it is wrong, has some probability p of failing, so its odds of failing 100 times is p ^ 100.  As you repeatedly test it, the value that p would have to have in order for you to not have seen a failure yet gets lower and lower.

Comment: Unfortunately this absolutely never happens.  Tests of true theories fail because of the imperfection in the experimental equipment, its execution, mistaken computations, random weather conditions...  whatever.  So we have to allow for a certain probability that a theory, though true *would still fail*.  Humans are notoriously bad at guessing this probability.  They tend to accept responsibility for the failure and not impute it to the theory -- even though that is the whole point..  And they do this over and over again, because they have unmeasured faith in their beliefs.

Comment: All told then, the idea of falsification actually killing a theory falls apart in practice.  Theories survive for the same reason humans are bad at induction to begin with.  We like to believe things and we don't estimate the likelihood of things we like and things we don't like on similar terms.  So this part of the theory is just wrong.  Only the part that discriminates between rival explanations for the same facts works.

Comment: @jobermark Ok, but this is an induction method. You have a number of singular events (the positive experiments) from which you state the trustworthiness of some universal theories. I mean, in why this way describing it can't work also for induction? I mean, it looks like inducted probability to me...

Comment: And still, this induction method says nothing. The odds get higher and higher maybe, but facing infinity they arw still 0 at the end.

Comment: It is Bayesian inference, not induction.  The probability is not spurious, it is statistically meaningful.  Also, science has no intention of proving a truth, only of establishing what futures are unlikely so we can be comfortable with our technology.  So infinity is irrelevant.  Scientific theories are *all* eventually displaced by better ones.  We have never seen a theory just live forever, and if we did, scientists would all be out of a job.  The goal is entirely different from that of a guessed probability of a philosophical truth based on repetition.

Comment: If you flip a coin 3000 times, you can get an excellent estimate of exactly how fair it is.  That is not induction, it is a mathematical application of the law of large numbers.  There is no ultimate truth here, only reliable statistics.  Because we are doing physics, not philosophy.

Comment: @jobermark what could i read on this topic? I mean, i know nothing about this Bauesian inference...

Comment: I don't have a reference at hand, hopefully there are some at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference

Comment: @jobermark you could flip a coin 3000 times and get only heads. And do the same for 3000 times and so on.  How can we justify the gap between our finite esperience and the infinite possibilities? We could have found that tossing a coin will result in a fifthy fifthy chance, just by coincidence...

Comment: Because infinity is irrelevant to science.  No justification is necessary because all you get is the odds you are wrong.  They will never be zero.  And you won't care.

Comment: @jobermark but science looks for universal theories, in space and time

Comment: And it can't find any. I pointed out that every theory expects to be replaced by a better one.  So only approximations are possible, or relevant.  We can get closer and closer to explaining something, but we know we cannot succeed completely.  All you can know is that you are usually not going backwards.  And statistics suffice for that.  Historians after Popper are much clearer on that notion.  Modernism collapsed, and it took the arrogance of science trying to read the mind of God with it.

Answer (score 1):

The standards Popper proposes are 'falsifiability' and 'audacity'.  A theories value is tied to its 'audacity' -- how much is risked upon the theory's falsifiability, and thus how much will be lost if it is found to be false.  So if other theories agree with it and would be taken down with it, they increase its value.

This whole concern has nothing to do with induction.  Statistical deduction is not induction.  It relies upon hypotheses always having a nonzero chance of being found wrong, and therefore continually multiplying some factor less than one into the odds of the entire surrounding structure surviving if we entertain the extending theory, reducing it.  This is Bayesian, not inductive.

I like to see this in Shannon terms.  More information correlates with more futures disallowed by the theory, because a future that refutes the theory is a falsification, and would be ruled out if the theory holds.  A theory's value is the quantity of information that it would contribute to the theory, if it were accepted.  That is its odds of falsification.

We cannot really measure those odds, but we can determine whether it is nonzero by imagining what kinds of futures it forbids, and whether those have some kind of positive measure not already covered by other aspects of the paradigm.  And we can subjectively compare our guesses about those odds, rating the theory's "audacity" against its competitors.

Comment: Ye but this doesn't answer the question. I know all those standards of the scientific theory for popper, but those are not the only one. He explicitly says that a theory gets more and more trustworthy the more it get corroborated, the more it passes checks/experiments. Why is that thou?